# Disable auto-start of postgres server on boot (Mac)

Tags: postgresql, configuration, startup, macos

Running a Mac.  I installed Postgresql 9 many years ago and configured it to auto-start.  Now I have upgraded to version 12 using brew, but on system restart version 9 server is still starting automatically.  I don't know how to determine what is starting it, I don't see anything in my bash_profile and I don't see a feature in brew or pg_ctl that allows me to disable an auto-start configuration.  I have no postgres files in /Library/LaunchAgents either.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In answer to [Prevent PostgreSQL from running at startup](https://superuser.com/q/244589) on Super User:

[ithinkiknowruby](https://superuser.com/users/506295/ithinkiknowruby) wrote:

> ```
> cd /Library/LaunchDaemons/
> sudo rm com.edb.launchd.postgresql-9.0.plist
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As of October 2023, you can disable automatically starting a Postgres.app database in the UI by:

1. Opening `Postgres.app`
2. Click the database on the left hand side (if you have more than one, you need to do this for each one).
3. Click `Server Settings`.
4. Uncheck `Automatically start server`.

[image: Screenshot demonstrating how to click Server Settings then unchecking Automatically start server on Postgres.app]

The .plist was not there for me, at least for Postgres version 16.

You might also want to go into `Login Items` (what Ventura calls items that start on login) and turn off `Postgres.app`, so the actual app doesn't start either on boot if you don't want that.